# Rails 3 templates: rendering multiple formats using the same template handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

From a single view file containing e.g. LaTeX code with ERB inserts, I would like to be able to:

1. render to a LaTeX source file, by evaluating the ERB
2. render to PDF, by compiling the previous result using a custom latex_to_pdf() function

The first case can be achieved by registering a template handler:

```
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :latex, LatexSource
```

where LatexSource is a subclass of ActionView::Template::Handler implementing call(template) or compile(template).

This allows a view file "action.tex.latex" to be accessed and processed correctly as "controller/action.tex".

The second case seems much harder though:

- how can the request "controller/action.**pdf**" be sent to the template handler as if it was "controller/action.tex", and pass the result through latex_to_pdf() before sending the response to the user?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just register another template handler `:pdf` whose `compile` method looks similar to this?:

```
def compile
   latex_to_pdf LatexSource.compile(template)
end
```

**Update:**
Ok, right, this results in the need of having the view duplicated (*action.tex.latex*, *action.tex.pdf*).

Next idea:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.latex 
  format.pdf { render :file => latex_to_pdf(render) } 
end
```

As far as I can remember, render returned the rendered template as String in Rails 2.3.
I don't know how it behaves in Rails 3.

You could experiment with [render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Rendering/render) or [_render_template](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Rendering/_render_template). If this works, we could think about how to make this more dry and comfortable for multiple actions.

Comment: Thanks, but that requires keeping two identical copies of the view file: "action.tex.latex" and "action.pdf.latex".
I guess the issue is in trying to fool the template finder that two different outputs can be generated from the same view file.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t use it myself (yet), but it looks as if https://github.com/jacott/rails-latex could do the job for you.